# Codeigniter Multiple Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I am trying to access a database that is placed remotely on another server. I can access that server remotely but I can't connect via my MySQL Connection settings. Here are my MySQL settings:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'myhostname';

$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'MyDb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I am not sure where I am making a mistake so if someone can point out the mistake it will be really helpful.

Comment: apparently there is something wrong on server side, check your access log or try log in there manually first

Comment: how do you access server? have you tried connecting to mysql without using CI? do you have a cpanel on remote server?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

First, check username and password for mysql (obviously username cannot be root and password cannot be blank for security reasons) and for hostname, you might have to supply IP address of your server where mysql is hosted. Rest configurations appear to be fine. You can ask for these information from your hosting company.

Comment: on local envoirment password can be blank